# resolving cursors with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to query the Twitter API for users' followers to compare the two. I am using a cursor to retrieve the list of users. I set it up using promises, where the first get request gets the users followers to a limit, then looks for the cursor passes the data into an array and then resolves with the value of the cursor into a the same recurring function until the cursor returns 0, when that happens I want to send it all in a res. When I set up my initial promises and use `promise.all` to resolve them and attach a `.then`, the promise. all resolves first. I've tried resolving the promise from the recurring function and then returning another promise to the first function but I can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas?

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const twitter = require("../controllers/twitter");

let object1 = {
  params: {
    screen_name: "xxxx",
    count: "40"
  }
};
let object = {
  params: {
    screen_name: "xxxxx",
    count: "40"
  }
};
let data = [];
router.get("", (req, res, next) => {
  let one = getUserFollowers("/1.1/followers/ids.json", object);
  let two = getUserFollowers("/1.1/followers/ids.json", object1);
  Promise.all([one, two]).then(console.log);
});

function getUserFollowers(uri, parameters) {
  twitter
    .get(uri, parameters)
    .then(resp => {
      let ids = resp.data.ids;
      data.push(...ids);

      return recurr(resp, uri, parameters);
    })
    .then(data => {
    //if instead I re console.log the data I can get it, but I need to resolve it back in the router so I can send it as a res. 
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(data);
        reject(error);
      });
    });
}

let recurr = (response, uri, params) => {
  if (response.data.next_cursor > 0) {
    params.params.cursor = response.data.next_cursor;
    return getUserFollowers(uri, params);
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve(data);
  }
};

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: `getUserFollowers` function doesn't return anything - did you mean `return twitter.get ..... etc`

Comment: `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve(data);
        reject(error);
      });` - a Promise can only be "completed" once. So that code makes no sense. But that whole `.then` can be removed anyway

Comment: `getUserFollowers` doesn't `return` the promise it creates

Comment: since `recurr` is only ever called inside `.then` ... you can just `return data` where you have `return Promise.resolve(data);`

Comment: wow Ive been staring at it for so long, didnt even notice that. You are right, unfortunately I can't try it for another 15 minutes lol. Will update in a bit

Comment: the fact that you have one global `data` that has data pushed by both `getUserFollowers` will probably cause you problems too

Comment: yea it returns only the last one, I will change that one after I get this part to work. Thanks...just waiting now

Comment: If I were to rewrite your code, https://pastebin.com/7dAbcZj9 would be a start

Comment: great that worked, if you want to post an answer I can accept it. Ill refactor my code to the one you posted as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistakes in your code:

`getUserFollowers` doesn't return anything - so, lets add a return before `twitter.get`

```
.then(data => {
//if instead I re console.log the data I can get it, but I need to resolve it back in the router so I can send it as a res. 
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(data);
    reject(error);
  });
});
```

This makes no sense for several reasons.

1. you can only "complete" a Promise once, so having resolve followed by reject means only resolve is executed ...
2. `.then` always returns a promise, so there's usually no need for a Promise constructor when the .then contains only synchronous code; and
3. what you're actually doing is a no-op ... you've received `data` in .then, done nothing to it, and in a complicated way, returned data out the other end

Since `recurr` is only ever called inside a `.then` you don't need to guarantee you're returning a Promise using `Promise.resolve` - however, I'd lose the recurr function altogether, it just complicates things in such simple code

he fact that you have one global `data` variable that has data pushed by both `getUserFollowers` will probably cause you problems too

Rewriting to fix all of the above, you get:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const twitter = require("../controllers/twitter");

let object1 = {
  params: {
    screen_name: "xxxx",
    count: "40"
  }
};
let object = {
  params: {
    screen_name: "xxxxx",
    count: "40"
  }
};

router.get("", (req, res, next) => {
    let one = getUserFollowers("/1.1/followers/ids.json", object, []);
    let two = getUserFollowers("/1.1/followers/ids.json", object1, []);
    Promise.all([one, two]).then(console.log);
});

function getUserFollowers(uri, parameters, data) {
    return twitter
    .get(uri, parameters)
    .then(resp => {
        let ids = resp.data.ids;
        data.push(...ids);
        if (resp.data.next_cursor > 0) {
            params.params.cursor = response.data.next_cursor;
            return getUserFollowers(uri, params, data);
        }
        return data;
    });
}

module.exports = router;
```